# Are questions of Boxing and Wrestling considered on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Generally when you see a question and answer board or a forum, `martial arts` are generally lumped under a category `sports` and separated from `boxing` and `wrestling`. With both being common components of `mixed-martial-arts`, are these questions on-topic? Or is this subjective and relative to the question itself? That is, questions like `When will Manny Pacquiao next fight Marquez?` are subjectively different from questions of training in specific techniques, so the judgment would be reserved for case by case basis.

Comment: Do the forums or boards you're referring to make a distinction as to what "martial arts" entails? They are probably referring to the numerous styles and varieties (I'm guessing of East Asian origin) that all have their own history and development that isn't like the practiced, organized sports of the West.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Personally I would consider them to be on topic along with with most other combat systems that exist as an organized system, e.g. [fencing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fencing), [kyudo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kyudo), [wrestling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrestling), etc.

In terms of actual matches though, unless it is a discussion of the techniques used (i.e. "Why did so-and-so use technique A as opposed to B?") I would consider them to be off topic and more of a general sports question.

Comment: This is essentially my position as well.

Answer (score 5):

In regards to "When will Manny Pacquiao next fight Marquez?". That is a question about a sport: boxing. I think that is off topic. However, the basis of the sport is boxing, which is completely on-topic if you ask me. MMA and wrestling are Martial Arts, as well.

Comment: Pacquiao vs Marquez is boxing not mma ;)   but your point still stands.

Comment: Right, jesus. I'm an idiot. I just wasn't focused on the specifics when I wrote the answer. I'll edit it :P

Answer (score 4):

I would consider them both as on-topic.The term should refer to include any type of combative practice for sport, self-defense, physical and mental development, and what have you regardless of whether it's East Asian, European, Western, or such.

Comment: So I can finally ask all my questions about the finer points of broadsword technique here? Hooray! :P

Comment: I'd love to see some questions on broadsword, rapier, and other more "western" combat systems ^_^

Comment: I'm actually fine with sword techniques :)

Comment: @Aarthi: Yes, please do ask.

Comment: I, oh gosh, I was joking, mostly, but now I *do* want to ask about technique. Hmm, I do have some friends who participate in SCA....

Comment: SCA and ARMA are both exactly the sort of thing I'd love to see here. Bring em! ^_^

Answer (score 3):

I would say anything pertaining to training boxing or wrestling is on topic, but questions about prizefights would be off-topic.